# Predicting intent based on entity identified

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am building a LUIS app where I want to predict the intent of the text, based on entity within it.

Example -

1. connect me to John   (this should get predicted as intent1)
2. connect me to 1000   (this should get predicted as intent2)

In above two utterances, John is name and 1000 is number. And name and number are entities I have defined in my model. So sentence 1 should get predicted as intent1 and sentence 2 should get predicted as intent2.

But when I test my model with same sentences, both gets predicted in 'Intent1'only. How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can add a prebuilt entity "Person" and prebuilt entity "Number" and use these entities as features for the respective intent.
Refer to this link for using entities as features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#entities-as-features

Comment: I am able solve this issue by solution you have given above. With addition to that I have to define some pattern for same.